# Convert the form content in html into .pdf format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How i can do this?

```
       <form>
        First name:<br>
       <input type="text"             name="firstname">
          Last name:<br>
       <input type="text"       name="lastname">
```

After submitting the form i want to make a pdf of that submitted form and store that  pdf file in my database.

Comment: how you are planning to save PDF in DB!!!?

Answer (score 0):

use itext sharp to do it use the tutorial here http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/80/create-pdfs-in-asp-net-getting-started-with-itextsharp
itextsharp source
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/